# Bizzare error in code::blocks

Tags: c++, arrays, macros, codeblocks, iostream

I get an Error in line 1: "Macro names must be identifiers" in this
and I can't fix this nor I can find a solution for this.
I'm not sure why am I getting this error because when I use Dev c++ it's fine, but at the same time the program crashes because arrays are too long, which doesn't happen in Code::blocks with this length for some reason.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n,m,t,l [800] [100],p1[100001],p2[100001],k1[100001],k2[100001],a1[100001],a2[100001],trsa[2],aia[2],swtch0,swtch1,swtch_u,krmbl[2];
    cin>>n;
    cin>>m;
    for(int yi=0;yi<n;yi++){
        for(int y=0;y<m;y++){
            cin>>l[y] [yi];
        }
    }
    cin>>t;
    for(int o=0;o<t;o++){
        cin>>p1[o];
        cin>>p2[o];
        cin>>k1[o];
        cin>>k2[o];
        cin>>a1[o];
        cin>>a2[o];
        p1[o]--;
        p2[o]--;
        k1[o]--;
        k2[o]--;
        a1[o]--;
        a2[o]--;
    }

    for(int o=0;o<t;o++){
        trsa[0]=0;
        if(p1[o]>k1[o]){
            trsa[0]=p1[o]-k1[o];
        }else if(p1[o]<k1[o]){
            trsa[0]=p1[o]+k1[o];
        }
        trsa[1]=0;
        if(p2[o]>k2[o]){
            trsa[1]=p2[o]-k2[o];
        }else if(p2[o]<k2[o]){
            trsa[1]=p2[o]+k2[o];
        }

        for( aia[0]=p1[o];aia[0]<trsa[0];aia[0]++){
            krmbl[0]=krmbl[0]+l[aia[0]] [aia[1]];
            if(aia[0]==a1[o]){
                if(aia[1]==a2[o]){
                    swtch0=1;
                }
            }

        }
        for( aia[1]=p2[o];aia[1]<trsa[1];aia[1]++){
            krmbl[1]=krmbl[1]+l[aia[0]] [aia[1]];
            if(aia[0]==a1[o]){
                if(aia[1]==a2[o]){
                    swtch0=1;
                }
            }
        }
        for( aia[1]=p2[o];aia[1]<trsa[1];aia[1]++){
            krmbl[1]=krmbl[1]+l[aia[0]] [aia[1]];
            if(aia[0]==a1[o]){
                if(aia[1]==a2[o]){
                    swtch1=1;
                }
            }

        }
        for( aia[0]=p1[o];aia[0]<trsa[0];aia[0]++){
            krmbl[0]=krmbl[0]+l[aia[0]] [aia[1]];
            if(aia[0]==a1[o]){
                if(aia[1]==a2[o]){
                    swtch1=1;
                }
            }

        }
        if(krmbl[1]>krmbl[0]){
            if(swtch1==1){
                cout<<"TAK"<<endl;

            }else{
                cout<<"NIE"<<endl;
            }
        }else if(krmbl[1]<krmbl[0]){
            if(swtch0==1){
                cout<<"TAK"<<endl;

            }else{
                cout<<"NIE"<<endl;
            }

        }else{
            if(swtch0==1){
                cout<<"TAK"<<endl;

            }else{
                cout<<"NIE"<<endl;
            }
        }
        if(swtch1==1){
                cout<<"TAK"<<endl;

        }else{
                cout<<"NIE"<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On a hunch: try eliminating the spaces in `l [800] [100]`.

Comment: This compiles fine in MSVC 2013.

Comment: ...and it compiles under gcc 4.92.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: the code::blocks compiler you know the one that's included alongside the installer

Comment: Also compiles fine C::B 13.12, gcc 9.2. Post the compiler commandline and error message, verbatim from the build log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it run in Dev C++ too by declaring all the arrays globally.
Large arrays declared globally (i.e. on heap) is possible,if u declare anything in the main or in any function it goes into the stack which has a smaller size hence your arrays did not work out. Try declaring it globally and it should work.

Comment: thanks this surely helped out because I'm really used to Dev c++